# Profile Form inline edit/ xeditable

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, codeigniter

I have this currently on my profile page,

```
<fieldset id="basic_information" class="collapse">
  <!-- Text input-->
    <div class="form-group">
    <label class="col-sm-2 control-label" for="textinput">Screen Name</label>
    <div class="col-sm-10">
    <input type="text" name="screen_name" placeholder="Screen Name" class="form-control"> 
    </div>
    </div>
```

Is there an up to date bootstrap library in which it's easy to use and has a tutorial for it?(current 2016 atleast) for inline edit. I want to make use of bootstrap as much as possible as i did above, i used bootstrap collapse function.

I'm trying this one out, https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/.

But i don't know if it's still fine to use as the latest release was 2013, that was like 4 years ago.

also is there any tutorial on this on how to use it extensively? The instructions on the site never goes into full detail with full examples. I'm still at the training wheels stage in regards to front-end development.

for example, can anyone give me an example on the input above how to use the inline editor toggle with the pencil?

P.S. I don't have extensive css knowledge, even before i started using bootstrap which is this year, i just made my own css without those fancy stuff. I'm really out of my element, this is the first time that i am trying to widen/broaden my horizon. If it was before, i'd probably just make 2 html pages, one for displaying profile details and one for editing. Maybe i'm chewing more than i can swallow and should probably take it slow but i learn by experience, it's a good and bad thing at the same time.

Comment: Don't know much about x-editable but the last git commit was 20 days ago, so I think you're okay there.

Comment: Currently reading the docs on their site. Took a 3 hour break to get my mind cleared up and voila. Gonna need some time to digest this. Hopefully, this library is still up to date with the latest updates of bootstraps and won't cause me unexpected problems.